# Textboxes on stage eventually disappearing - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a digital clock with 7 stripes on 6 numbers.

I replaced the stripes with textboxes filled with 'I''s. So im letting them disappearing on each time with the code: textbox.text = ""

I did all the coding, but the textboxes on screen will eventually disappear?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough code. Perhaps you are invoking `gotoAndStop()` and losing the valid textbox reference, for example.

Comment: Well I'm using this code with every minute and second.
A total of 1100 lines of code.

`if (seconds==55)`
`{ linksonder2.text = "";
 rechtsboven2.text = "";
 linksonder1.text = "";
 rechtsboven1.text = "";
}`

Comment: well, do you re-establish the "I"s back when your 7-digit number needs to show the symbol?

Comment: What is the real problem??? _"the textboxes on screen will eventually disappear?"_ why ask this? Since "Yes, but you must first write code to make them disappear" is the obvious Answer...

Comment: Anyways why not just make one MovieClip object with frames of "stripes" shapes for counting from `0` to `9` (= total of 10 frames). If you later make this MC as a class then you can just `import` it and make unique `new` instances (copies) of same MC. Pseudo-code example : Where time = HH:MM:SS. Make two copies for each `A` + `B` hours of time by using `var Ha = new stripeMC; var Hb = new stripeMC;`. To display 18:00:00 just say `Ha.gotoAndStop(1)` gives frame 1 with "1" stripe. Send `Hb` to frame 8 for "8" stripe. Result is `18` if you position those `Ha` & `Hb` MovieClips next to each other.

Comment: Did you consider using just a digital font? I'm not going to search 7-stripes for you but there is plany of digitalized fonts see http://audionysos.cba.pl/Odtwarzacz.html for example (10 years old project warning :P)